# DJI P3 Advanced Mobile SDK Virtual Stick Control does not work?

Tags: java, android-studio, dji-sdk

Im working on a project that I should be controlling the DJI drone with via a computer. Therefore, first of all I need to implement a code that works on the mobile SDK. However, the virtual sticks on DJI Sample APK does not work, any suggestions?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, after completing the project I can actually answer my own question.

The problem was the sending rate of the DJI Sample SDK when I changed it to 10Hz and it actually worked.

PS: If you think it's too hard to control as in the controller, you can change the control system, which is the flight controller settings.

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/flightController_concepts.html#coordinate-systems

I changed it to the Course Lock orientation which can be controlled in the sample SDK as well.(angle/velocity)

To see what I did you can check the link below;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sQ5uMXWnPU&list=PLWuZdcP_lwyr_GSLl9yzC_Li_q2421o2t&index=5

Love

Answer (score 1):

The Virtual RC Protocol (virtual sticks) does work on the QT/Windows version of the Onboard SDK. It might help you to look into the messages that get passed there.

Comment: I have also tested it on the Linux version of the Onboard SDK.